# Can I reference a script file on Info.plist?

Tags: macos, eclipse-rcp

When creating an .app bundle on Mac, can I create a script file and reference it as CFBundleExecutable on Info.plist file?  If so, how?

I tried running

`chmod 777 my_script_file`

and then adding

`<key>CFBundleExecutable</key> <string>my_script_file</string>`

to my Info.plist file, but then I'll get the message "you cannot open this app because it is not compatible with this type of Mac" when I double click my package. (The exact message might be slightly different, my Mac is in Portuguese.)

**Edit**:

I need to do this because I develop an Eclipse RCP Application that uses a native launcher to be started.  This launcher (referenced on the Info.plist file under the CFBundleExecutable key) is not working correctly on MacOS Sonoma and I can't change it.  But I can bypass it and launch my application using `java -jar my-app.jar`.

This is what I'm aiming to do.  Have this Java call as a script file and reference it on the Info.plist to have it executed when I open MyApplication.app, in place of the native launcher.

Comment: This definitely *used to* work (I’ve done it) but even in older versions of macOS there were severe restrictions with it, and it’s entirely possible that this no longer works. If you absolutely need to run a shell scrpt I therefore recommend writing a generic application launcher as a binary executable in your compiled language of choice, and letting that execute the shell script.

Comment: Can you give a complete reproducible example ?

Comment: @Philippe, I'm afraid not.  I develop a huge Java application using RCP and I don't have enough knowledge on Mac to create a simple example.  In case it helps to understand my problem, I updated the question to add further information.  Thanks for asking.